# Looping over jagged arrays in c# --- using foreach instead of for?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm working on a project, and I find myself repeatedly looping over a jagged array using nested `for` loops. I'm wondering if there might be a neater way of doing it using `foreach`?

Here's what I mean:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < xDimension; ii++)
  {
    for (int jj = 0; jj < yDimension; jj++)
      {
        OutputArray[ii][jj] = someFunction(InputArray[ii][jj]);
      }
  }
```

Note that I'm using Jagged arrays even though my data is of fixed size because jagged arrays are faster than multidimensional arrays. Unfortunately speed is an issue with this project so unfortunately performance will outweigh my own OCD coding desires.

Is there a way to do this with `foreach` that avoids the nested `for` loops but puts the output data in the correct place in the `OutputArray`? Wwould there be any benefit/loss from doing so (if it is possible) other than having slightly neater code?

Comment: You could use `i` and `j` instead of `ii` and `jj` :)  Otherwise I don't see a way around `for` loops since you need the indices to populate the second array.

Comment: "speed is an issue with this project" - is array access the bottleneck in your project?  Have you measured it?

Comment: @DStanley I haven't measured it directly but I am making 10s of billions of loop iterations so whilst loop access might not be the biggest problem I'm not that keen to make the loop performance worse ;)

Comment: Fair enough - though if speed is really a big concern then I would invest in a profiling tool to make sure you're improving the slowest parts first.  Adding a supercharger doesn't help much if your tires are flat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is "neater":

```
OutputArray = InputArray.Select(x => x.Select(y => someFunction(y)).ToArray())
                        .ToArray();
```

But I would just go with the loops, because this LINQ version has a significant disadvantage: It creates new arrays instead of using the existing ones in `OutputArray`. This argument is moot if you create `OutputArray` right before the loop you showed us.
Furthermore, it is quite a lot harder to read.

Comment: Can you expand on this? `.Select`, `=>`, and `.ToArray` are all new to me. What will the performance be like?

Comment: @FakeDIY: It's [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) and lambdas. If you don't know it, I suggest you take a few hours to read up on it :) It's surely out of the scope of this question to explain these concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it was LINQ. Unfortunately for reasons beyond my control I'm stuck on .NET framework 2.0 so LINQ is not available to me just now.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to create a jagged array as the result, you could use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) twice:

```
var result = Array.ConvertAll(input,
                              array => Array.ConvertAll(array, SomeFunction));
```

This is slightly more efficient than using `Select`/`ToArray` from LINQ, as it *knows* it's converting an array to another array, so can create the target arrays immediately. Using `Select` followed by `ToArray` requires the results to be built up gradually, as if you were putting them into a `List<T>`, copying them when the buffer is exhausted - and then "right-sizing" the array at the end.

On the other hand, using LINQ (as per Daniel's answer) would probably be more idiomatic these days... and the performance difference will *usually* be insignificant. I thought I'd give this as another option :)

(Note that this creates new arrays, ignoring the existing `OutputArray`... I'm assuming you can get rid of the creation of the existing `OutputArray`, although that may not be the case...)

Comment: +1 Clever.  I was working up an answer that used a `Func<T,T>` and completely forgot about `ConvertAll`.

Answer (score 1):

You could get data *out* of the jagged array more easily using a `foreach`, but as you wouldn't have variables indicating the indexes you wouldn't be able to *set* a value of the array very effectively, like you do in your example.

If you just wanted to *read* the values though, you can do this:

```
foreach(int n in OutputArray.SelectMany(array=>array))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

The `SelectMany` is needed to flatten the sequence, so that instead of being a sequence of sequences it is just a single sequence.

Comment: @Antonijn: I strongly dispute the "well known" part here. Care to provide a reference?

Comment: @Antonijn Your assumption is flawed.  The performance cost is quite small.

Comment: @Servy I don't know where I got that one from then. I'm sure I read it somewhere. Well, maybe the internet isn't always right ;)

Comment: @Antonijn A lot of people think it's a lot more expensive than it is, or they end up using it improperly and make it more expensive than it needs to be (with it being easy to use, it's easy to use the more expensive methods when you just don't need the functionality they give you).

Answer (score 0):

You can even get the indices out with LINQ:

```
foreach (var t in InputArray.SelectMany(
    (inner, ii) => inner.Select((val, jj) => new { val, ii, jj })))
{
    OutputArray[t.ii][t.jj] = someFunction(t.val);
}
```

but, to be honest, the twin-`for`-loop construct is a lot more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, just for fun:

```
foreach (var item in InputArray.SelectMany(x => x).Select((value, index) => new {value, index}))
{
    var x = item.index / yDimension;
    var y = item.index % yDimension;
    OutputArray[x][y] = someFunction(item.value);
}
```

I'd just stick with the nested loops, though.